Liaison dans le groupe nominal « maint homme » ?
On fait les liaisons pour les combinaisons suivantes avec « homme ».

les hommes, un homme, cet homme, …

Cependant faire la liaison dans la prononciation de « maint homme » me parait bizarre. Peut-on vraiment faire cette liaison ?

Quelle que soit la réponse, l'expression n'est pas très courante, surtout en langue parlée, encore moins dans la vie de tous les jours...

Peux-tu préciser pourquoi ça te parait bizarre ? Moi ce qui me parait difficile à faire c'est d'enchainer la voyelle nasale avant ɛ̃ et la voyelle arrière ɔ. Alors qu'en intercalant la dentale t entre les deux ça coule tout seul.

@Frank Il n'y a pas que vous et votre langué parlée, et morte, ils y a les gens qui ont besoin de lire un extrait occasionnellement, en particulier des littéraires. On ne pense pas qu'à votre langue de troquet.

@None Voir mon commentaire sous la première réponse.

@Frank Rappelle-toi quand tu déclamais de la poésie à l'école et au lycée  ! mɛ̃tɔm (qui m'entend lorsqu'ainsi je la vante...)

@None Maintes fois j'ai déclamé, / maints poèmes passionés, / par maints auteurs à la page consignés, / à maintes reprises écorchés...

Non, cette liaison se fait toujours. Si elle te paraît bizarre, c'est probablement parce que maint n'est plus trop utilisé de nos jours.

Non, c'est peut-être parce que ça rappelle le féminin « mainte ».

Moult origines peuvent l'expliquer, c'est vray.

@LPH Presque toutes les liaisons au singulier se prononcent comme le féminin (si le -e du féminin est complètement muet) !

"maint" est encore employé aujourd'hui dans l'expression "maint et maint" qui n'est pas très fréquente.

@Graffito Oui, maintes est beaucoup plus courant que maint ou maints.

@Graffito Je ne connais pas maint et maint.

@Jiliagre Oui, surtout dans l'expression "maintes et maintes fois" .
